# ssh: adding private key to ssh-agent before copying public key to remote server

Tags: ssh

I've used `ssh-keygen` to generate a ssh key pair, and then `ssh-copy-id` to copy the public key to the remote server. This has worked for all systems in my local network. I followed instructions similar to [this link](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id)

However, on bitbucket and github, I see this additional step of adding the private key to the `ssh-agent` using `ssh-add <private key>`

[This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) explains what this additional step but why is that not needed for my local network when it is needed for github and bitbucket?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "[Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent)" documented on GitHub (same on GitLab) is only there if you generate a private SSH key protected by a passphrase (meaning, encrypted)

The idea is that, for a private SSH key used for authenticating to a remote *public* service like GitHub or GitLab, it is better to have an encrypted key, which makes it less dangerous if said key is leaked.

This is different for a private SSH key used inside a LAN (in your local network): using a passphrase is still a good idea but not mandatory: if the SSH key leak, you still need access to the LAN in order to use it.